# When using spring security how to allow any user access to a resource without going through the configured filters?

Tags: java, spring, jhipster

My login/authentication logic is based on jhipster and implements remember-me filter. I would like to allow all users (no authentication required) access to the configuration endpoint, /configuration. It seems that the correct way to do so is to add the following to the filter chain:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf()
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new SimpleCORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
            .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
            .key(securityRememberMeKey)
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/api/v1/authentication")
            .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
            .usernameParameter("some")
            .passwordParameter("some")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/api/v1/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/configuration").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/generalEvent*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/account").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/account/reset_password/init").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/account/reset_password/finish").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

As one can see the /configuration endpoint has permitAll() which allows the user to get the configuration with no authentication but the remember-me filter will still be called which is an undesired result. is there a way to avoid the remember-me filter?